# How to credit layers fom OpenLayers plugin for pdf/printed maps?

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin, bing-maps

Anyone who has some insight into copyright law, went already through the terribly long terms of use and able to describe how should be the layers from OpenLayers plugin referenced / credited in PDF or printed maps? In the plugin there are links as follows:

The terms of service of the used map providers apply!

Selected links: 
[OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright), 
[Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), 
[Microsoft® Bing™ Maps](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html)

But after scan through these it all appears to me not saying anything about use for printed maps or PDFs. I must admit though I haven't read the whole thing word by word yet and hope I won't have to.

Comment: As I understand Google's and Bing's TOS it's not allowed to use their content outside their API, so there is no way to use such prints legally. But as good as you, I'm looking for comments from somebody who has insight into copyright law.

Comment: Is it for personal use? I suspect in part that plays a large role in what you can do with it legally.

Comment: @JonoPatterson No, I am interested in use of these as background for presenting plans etc. in business reports. But I am interested also in (semi)personal use. I have seen a lot of blogs using screens from Google maps etc., many blogs also runs ad system and I believe are somewhere between personal and professional etc.